# jQuery: Slider detect scrollDown or scrollUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which will make a simple slider with buttons to navigate.

Now I need to make this slider controllable with scrolling.

When user scroll down will be moved to the next slider also reverse.

Buttons will be available too. So there will be 2 options on how to control it. With buttons next and back also with scrolling down or up.

Is there any option of how to do it in the easiest way?

```js
var lottieone = document.getElementById('lottieone');
var lottietwo = document.getElementById('lottietwo');
var lottiethree = document.getElementById('lottiethree');
var lottiefour = document.getElementById('lottiefour');

$('#lottieone').show();
$('#lottietwo').hide();
$('#lottiethree').hide();
$('#lottiefour').hide();


function missionsSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').show();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function missionsSlideBacc() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').show();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function researchSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').hide();
  $('#lottiethree').show();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function educationSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').hide();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider">
  <div id="lottieone" class="lottieSlide">
    <div class="content">
      <button onclick="missionsSlide()">HOME</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottietwo" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>MISSIONS</h1>
      <button onclick="researchSlide()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottiethree" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>RESEARCH</h1>
      <button onclick="missionsSlideBacc()">Back</button>
      <button onclick="educationSlide()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottiefour" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
      <button onclick="researchSlide()">Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet.

```js
$(document).on('mousewheel', '.slider', function (e) {
   var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
   if (delta > 0) alert("scrolled Up");
   if (delta < 0) alert("scrolled Down");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is highly repeated question, so you might find multiple solution for it as well